# Where to find a Juvenile Wolf?

Tags: guild-wars-2

So I've now got all the Ranger pets except the [Wolf](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Juvenile_Wolf).

Does anyone know where to find a Juvenile Wolf? Having had a search around it seems the only place is in World v World.

Does this creature exist for charming in the PvE world somewhere? As it will make it easier for me to reach.

http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Juvenile_Wolf
Not to be confused with the Alpine Wolf.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's also the option to choose it as your starting pet if you create a Norn Ranger.

Otherwise, it seems that the [Juvenile Wolf](http://gw2.mmorpg-life.com/wolf-ranger-pet/2493/) is available only through World vs World.

Comment: Not sure this answer is really adding anything, considering I stated it's available in WvW in the question.

Comment: @DavidYell Considering that the *only* answer is "No, it's not available in PvE at all, it's only located in WvW", I'm not exactly sure what else could be added to this, honestly.

Comment: I must have misinterpreted it when I read it. I read it as just repeating what I already knew back to me, rather than confirming it.

Comment: Something else that could be added is that you can find a Juvenile Alpine Wolf in Hoelbrak.

Comment: The Alpine Wolf is different to the Wolf, in the same way the Red Moa is different to the Pink one.